# Unit Testing that HttpResponseMessage Contains the Desired Response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a Web API controller and right now I have the following code:

```
public class PicklistsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IPicklistRepository _repository;

    public PicklistsController(IPicklistRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetPicklistValues(string entityName, string fieldName)
    {
        if(_repository.Exists(entityName, fieldName))
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, _repository.Get(entityName, fieldName));

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to test this method and all I really want to do is verify that the HttpResponseMessage contains values in the POCO PicklistItem when the repository finds this combination of values.  Being new to this framework, I don't understand the internal workings of HttpResponseMessage very well, and what I've found on this site and through general googling tells me to use various ReadAsync methods on its Content, but I don't really want to do use async if I can avoid it.  I really just want to verify that the thing I stuffed into the object I'm returning is in the object when I return it.  Here's what I have so far with the unit test (using JustMock to setup the repository, Target is the CUT):

```
public void Returns_Picklist_Item_JSON_When_Results_Exist()
{
    Repository.Arrange(repo => repo.Exists(EntityName, FieldName)).Returns(true);

    const int value = 2;
    const string label = "asdf";
    var mynewPicklistItem = new PicklistItem() { Label = label, Value = value };
    Repository.Arrange(repo => repo.Get(EntityName, FieldName)).Returns(Enumerable.Repeat<PicklistItem>(mynewPicklistItem, 1));

    var response = Target.GetPicklistValues(EntityName, FieldName);
    //Assert.IsTrue(I don't know what to do here -- suggestions appreciated);
}
```

Any ideas for the Assert?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree/fundamentally misunderstanding how this should be working?  Thanks...

Comment: There's a `Content` field on `HttpResponseMessage`, couldn't you just check that it contains the string you expect?  You control the object that's going in, you could test that the same object is coming out.

Comment: Well, that's the property I've been banging my head against -- Intellisense gives me a Headers property and then a bunch of methods, most of which return booleans or involve async.  If there's something that I can cast this to in order to get what I want, that'd be perfect (ToString() on it just returns the type information).

Comment: You mean when you do `response.`, intellisence says `Content` isn't one of the properties? Or you just aren't sure how to look into the `HttpContent`?

Comment: I can get at response.Content, but I don't know how to cast it to anything useful or to use its properties/methods to get what I want out of it.

Comment: @Erik - if the `Content` is an object then try casting it as `ObjectContent` - the `Value` property should contain your object. If it's a `StreamContent` though then I don't know of other way than to do ReadAsAsync. Still you can block on the `Result` of the task to see the response.

Comment: @JoannaTurban  Bingo!  Thanks!  Make it an answer and claim your 15 :)

Comment: @Erik - there you go :-) I'm glad that it helped

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the `Content` is an object then try casting it as `ObjectContent` - the `Value` property should contain your object.

If it's a `StreamContent` though then I don't know of other way than to do `ReadAsAsync`. Still you can block on the Result of the task to see the response.

Here is an example:

```
var response = Target.GetPicklistValues(EntityName, FieldName);
ObjectContent objContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;
PicklistItem picklistItem = objContent.Value as PicklistItem;
```

Answer (score 19):

I am using Web API 2.1 and there is a function called `TryGetContentValue`:

```
[Test]
public void TheTestMethod()
{
    // arrange

    var ctrl = new MyController();

    ctrl.Request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestMessage>();  // using nSubstitute
    ctrl.Configuration = Substitute.For<HttpConfiguration>();

    // act

    HttpResponseMessage result = ctrl.Get();

    MyResponse typedresult;
    result.TryGetContentValue(out typedresult);     // <= this one

    // assert
}
```